# Textbook reccommendations

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, book-recommendation, poisson-summation-formula

I'm looking to find an easy lay-man explanation of the Poisson Summation Formula and a few extra questions on the same. It would be great if someone could recommend a few to me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Classical and Modern Fourier Analysis by Grafakos

Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces, by Stein, Elias and  Weiss, Guido

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at these! :)